# Tool to extract list of Open Source components from Gradle file

Tags: open-source, library

We publish open source Android modules, and we need to create a list of dependencies we use (name, version, license, website).

Rather than preparing the list by hand (and having to keep it up-to-date), I want to automate this process: all dependencies are listed in build.gradle files. I should be able to extract module name and version and map them to license and website.

I haven't yet found a tool that does it, but I feel there must be at least one.